# What do I need to understand from a security standpoint to be a front end reactjs/react-native engineer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, security

I was wondering if someone could explain to me what I need to know from a security standpoint to work with reactjs/react-native?  Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: It's too general. You could take whole courses to answer that.

Comment: I don't think so.  The only data is in the state otherwise you just have to make secure api and database calls and display the data safely.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I know there's like owasp too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you that are interested check out owasp top ten.